# TRelativePanel circular dependency

Tags: delphi, vcl

In the Delphi 10+ versions one of new introduced VCL components is TRelativePanel, which allows easy layout of controls on the form.

But sometimes without any clear reasons circular dependency starts to occur, while clearly no circular setup was made.

Exact message is 'RelativePanel error: Circular dependency detected. Layout could not complete'.

What is the reason?

Comment: *But sometimes without any clear reasons circular dependency starts to occur, while clearly no circular setup was made.* Please provide an example of such situation. How can it be reproduced?

Comment: @TomBrunberg
As expected, error on the EB top level quality standards, in my example it occurs only if there is combo box on the panel, which has nothing to do with relative alignment at all: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/FGKVqp0vbmoQZQ.   
And definitely occurred for me in other form which had TRichEdit

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and 
note the sentence "Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included **in the question itself**." Links (that might become invalid) to external sites are no good for future visitors that might look for a solution to the same problem as you have. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible hidden reason is in the wrong order in the ControlCollection property of the TRelativePanel, which does not sort controls automatically during layout phase as expected.
Controls order in the section must be coordinated to layout dependency order.